# Get the final result of a chain of Sequelize Promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sequelize.js

I'm working in an endpoint in an Express app, and it needs to return a group of Story records that belong to a specific User. I'm using a JSON Web Token submitted with the request to identify the user. From there, I'm finding their associated Projects (through a join table, UserProjects). I'm then looping over each project to find its associated Stories.

Ultimately, I need an array of stories to return to the user as JSON.

```
router.route('/')
  .get((request, response) => {
    let token = request.headers['reax-tracker-access-token'];

    jwt.verify(token, 'secret', (err, decoded) => {
      User.find({ where: { id: decoded.user } })
      .then( (user) => {
        return user.getProjects()
        .then( (projects) => {
          return projects.map( (project) => {
            return project.getStories()
            .then( (stories) => {
              return stories.map( (story) => {
                return story
              })
            })
          })
        })
      })
      .then((stories) => {
        response.json(stories)
      })
    })

  })

router.route('/:stories');
```

which returns:

```
[
  {
    "isFulfilled": false,
    "isRejected": false
  },
  {
    "isFulfilled": false,
    "isRejected": false
  },
  {
    "isFulfilled": false,
    "isRejected": false
  }
]
```

This makes sense to me, because if I use `setInterval` to wait in the final `then`, I get the results I'm expecting.

```
.then((stories) => {
  return setInterval(function() {
    response.json(stories)
  }, 2000)
})
```

How can I achieve the same effect as the interval with the appropriate Promise syntax?

Comment: While you are using promises wrong - you can just return and chain them without nesting them - the architecture is pretty poor. Instead of making all those requests, is there any one you can make just one or two of them? Also, the problem begins where you are using `.map` which doesn't return a promise.

Comment: Also, `return stories.map(story) => { return story })` accomplishes absolutely nothing.

Comment: You should be using eager loading to fetch all of the data in one query, rather than doing a bunch of nested queries, as described in the docs: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/models-usage/#eager-loading

Comment: Thanks, @Jordan. That was really helpful and got me going on the right path.

Comment: Since the result you want is stories, you should be querying the Story model, not the User model. I think it would look something like: `Story.findAll({ include: [ { model: Project, include: [ { model: User, where: { id: decoded.user } } ] } ] }).then(stories => response.json(stories))`. You might not even need Project in there if you have a `through` relation defined, but I'm not sure.

Comment: At any rate, you definitely shouldn't be doing more than one `findAll`. The whole point of using a relational database is that you can JOIN across tables and get all of your data in one query.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the comments on the original question and spending some more time with the Sequelize docs, I found a solution to the issue I was experiencing. This version avoids some of the nesting @Adam pointed out, and it takes advantage of the eager loading feature from Sequelize @Jordan pointed out. I'm sure it could still be improved upon, and I'd be happy for any input on how to do so.

```
router.route('/')
  .get((request, response) => {
    let token = request.headers['reax-tracker-access-token'];

    jwt.verify(token, 'secret', (err, decoded) => {
      User.find(
        {
          where: { id: decoded.user}
        }
      )
      .then( (user) => {
        return UserProject.findAll(
          {
            where: {
              userId: user.id
            }
          })
      })
      .then((userProjects) => {
        let projectIds = userProjects.map((up) => {
          return up.dataValues.projectId
        })
        return Story.findAll({
          where: {
            projectId: projectIds
          }
        })
      })
      .then((stories) => {
        response.status(200).json(stories)
      })
    })
  })
```

One of the big things I was doing wrong was returning non-Promises and trying to chain them with `then` calls:

```
.then( (projects) => {
          return projects.map( (project) => {
            return project.getStories()
            .then( (stories) => {...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue where I was receiving

```
{
    "isFulfilled": false,
    "isRejected": false
}
```

after using sequelize to create entities. Ultimately, I just forgot to `await` the `repository.create<>(...data)` call. Once I added `await repository.create<>(...data)` everything was as expected.